# Find Button not showing up in report through .Net Application

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services

When a ssrs report is generated, we generally see a "Find" button and text in the top tab. I can see this textbox and button when fetching report directly but while calling this report from my .NET application, the duo is missing. Any specific setting we need to do to achieve it ?

Comment: Is this the find button that what you are trying to say in the ssrs report? http://prntscr.com/8w7f5i?  i just want to clarify because I'm also doing reports using ssrs.

Comment: Yes. It is the default button we get in reports.

Comment: It is only find button to find particular text in the resultset which we have received on the screen. It doesnot hit DB , the Find | Next button in below link screen. http://bhushan.extreme-advice.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Call-SSRS-Report-With-Parameters-From-ASP.NET-5.png

Comment: try this tutorial bro http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15469/Integrating-Reporting-Services-Into-a-Web-App you could find other some examples online how to pass .net param to your report. My report is a bit complicated is this will not be a good example for starter.

Comment: here another good example bro http://bhushan.extreme-advice.com/call-ssrs-report-with-prameters-from-asp-net-web-application/

Comment: Bot, thanks for providing the links. But may be you did not get what exactly i am asking for. My parameters or data do not have any problem. Where we navigate to next page of reports i.e pagination etc is given, there a find button is by default present in reports. That button is not showing up in report when integrated with SSRS. It has to do with properties of C# or SSRS.